# How to test equality constraint in two equations using two different datasets

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, stata

I have two equations to estimate on two different datasets.I want to test if the coefficient for x are the same. The two equations are 
    $Y_{1t} = \alpha_{11}*X_{1t}+ \alpha_{12} * X_{2t} $ and  $Y_{1t} = \alpha_{21}*X_{1t}+ \alpha_{22} * X_{2t} $. 
The two equations are estimated using two samples of the same dataset. In the first data set , $Z==1$, and the second, $Z==2$. But since the populations is a panel , and $Z$ changes over time. so the same individual could appear in both samples. I am estimating the two equations using fixed effects model.

I have two questions for the procedure.

- How is the test statistics constructed for constraints $\alpha_{11}=\alpha_{12}$
- Issue in implementation. Some has suggested using suest in stata. But I am running a panel regression. And suest does not work with xtfeg. I know there is a routine xtsur . But it constantly gives me an error message. And others seem to run into the same problem. So my question is What is the proper way to implement this in a statistical software (Stata, R ,etc).

Comment: You are running two fixed-effects panel regressions on data sets where there's no correlation except within each panel?

Comment: I suspect there would be correlations. The two samples are separated based on their smoking status in each wave. So there could be individuals showing in both two waves, due to quitting and relapsing.

Comment: You really need to clarify what you're doing and the structure of your data. In the mean time, take a look at the Blackwell SJ paper cited in the comments [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/109094/7071).

Comment: There also might a way to do this using `gsem`.

Comment: I edited the questions for background.

Comment: I'm still a little confused at what you are asking. You have two datasets, that represent two points in time, where some individuals are present in both datasets? Have you considered stacking the data and treated it as a repeated-measures model? You will need to take into account clustering of some observations due to belonging to the same individual. You wouldn't need suest if the data are stacked into a single dataset, and it is fairly simple to test whether a coefficient is constant across two points in time on the same dataset.

Comment: It's a longitudinal survey. So an individual is repeated surveyed in different time. But he may smoke or not in different point of time. I divide the data into two pieces, smokers and nonsmokers. So a respondent could be smoking and not smoking in two waves. He could be present in both datasets.